# Right-align two divs

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, is it possible to right-align two DIVs?

I have a title and I want to right-align a more link underneath it. The site is internal and so, unfortunately, IE7 is the primary browser. (We will upgrade to IE8 before the end of the year, and some are using Chrome). I'd like to avoid javascript, but I'm open to it.

The title changes, so absolute widths won't work. It should look something like this:

```
| Arbitrarily long title text
|                     more...
```

I've been all over the Googles looking for a solution, but everything I've found so far relates to right-aliging the content of a DIV, or to right-aligning a DIV to the page, or right-aligning a DIV within an absolutely sized DIV.

I can show you my efforts so far, but as none of them work, I don't think they're of much use.

```
<html>
    <body>

        <div style="float:left;">
            Arbitrarily long title
            <div style="float:right">more...</div>
        </div>

        <div style="width:0px; overflow:visible; white-space:nowrap;">
            Arbitrarily long title
            <div style="float:right">more...</div>
        </div>

        <!-- This sort of simulates what I want, but the title length is arbitrary and I don't want to have to measure the text -->
        <div style="width:120px;">
            Arbitrarily long title
            <div style="float:right">more...</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

If anyone knows of a duplicate question, I'd love to learn the secrets of your Google-fu!

**EDIT**
Image, as requested. The link is bordered with red. (I had to set the margin-left to 70px to achieve this affect.)

[image]

Comment: please provide the image you want to do.... even image made by paint will be very helpful

Comment: Hmm, this is going to sound naive: what's wrong with `text-align`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way you might solve it (I don't have IE here, so I can't test it now, but I used similar styling on cross browser before).

**Snippet**

```css
.title-block {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.more {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

​
```

```html
<div class="title-block">
  <div>Arbitrarily long title</div>
  <div class="more">more...</div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div style="float:left; position: relative">
  <div>Arbitrarily long title</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; right: 0">more...</div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/efixij/7/edit

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Unfortunately, this right-aligns the "more..." div to the right of the page. Maybe if I was using a non-stupid browser it would work, but the IE7 decision is way above my pay grade. :)

Comment: Indeed it does. IE, go figure. Edited answer should work, @Jasper-de-vries had it

Comment: Now the more-div is positioned outside the containing div: http://jsbin.com/efixij/9/edit you need a `padding-bottom` of at least one line (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12568324/880619)

Comment: In the words of my generation, w00t! Thanks, this did it. (Thanks @JasperdeVries - already figured out the padding part.)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be very useful but give it a look:
Align main Div content to left and then the "more" div to righ as here :

```
<div style="float: left;">     
    <div>
        Arbitrarily extra extra long title here
    </div>    
    <div style="float:right;">
        more...
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div> Business area </div>
    <div> Inernal Audit </div>
    <div style="text-align: right;"><a href="#"> More... </a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to give some explanation in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="one">
        Arbitrarily long title Arbitrarily long title
        <div class="two">more...</div>
    </div>

.one{
  width:auto; 
  float:left;
  border:thin red solid;
  margin:5px;
}
.two{
  float:right;
}
```

​[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/tNRAr/1/)