# Right-aligning a div under centered text

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have my main content div, and I want to create a title that is centered in this parent div, and then have a subtitle underneath that is right-aligned to the edge of the centered text. I've been having a real difficult time getting this to work, and all the examples I can find on this site and others seem to get messed up when the top text is centered (as opposed to, say, left-aligned to the parent div).

It should look like this (where App Title is centered in a larger div):
[image]

The closest I can find is this question ([Right-align two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568142/right-align-two-divs)) but it seems that `float: left` is very important to making this work, which doesn't seem to work for my case. Other solutions seem to involve `display: table` but I was struggling to get the effect I want.

The title div needs to be variable width and I don't need to support ancient browsers. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should post your HTML and any CSS you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 ways, one using `flex` and the other using `inline-block`. Basically create a container for the titles, center that container, then align the subtitle to the right.

```css
* {margin:0;}
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex h2 {
  text-align: right;
}

.ib {
  text-align: center;
}
.ib header {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ib h2 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
  <header>
    <h1>app title</h1>
    <h2>subtitle</h2>
  </header>
</section>

<section class="ib">
  <header>
    <h1>app title</h1>
    <h2>subtitle</h2>
  </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I thought I had for sure tried the inline-block solution in one of the many attempts I tried (and then erased, hence why I had to link to a previous stackoverflow question), but I suppose it was some combination of needing three separate elements, the top one centered and the next one with inline-block, that I didn't consider.